# Objective C...Define structures?

Tags: objective-c

I am new programming and Objective-C in general. Do I declare a struct in the interface and define it in the implementation use a void method ?...

```
@interface Elements : NSObject {


struct elementZ{

    NSString *name;
    float molarmass;

}elements[81];
```

Now that I have declared it..where do I initialize the elements[81] array?

Comment: I think you're confusing structs with arrays.

Comment: I am declaring an array of elementZ structure

Comment: yes you already declared it. what do you mean by defining it. Initialization? then you may add a `-(id)init` method to your implementation.

Comment: @Kai - OP probably meant to initialize `elementZ` members.

Comment: @VenDiaS: I have edited your question to change define to initialise.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as is for me. Then you can access the data in your implementation like so:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 
    elements[2].name = @"hello";
    NSLog(elements[2].name);
}
```

This will print 'hello' to the console.

Answer (score 1):

**Do I declare a struct in the interface and define it in the implementation use a void method ?**

Yes it is what you think since Objective C is a super set of C. Have a method, that takes no arguments and returns **void** and initialize the member variables of `struct elementz` through `elements[81];`. Probably by running a loop from 0 to 80. As an example -

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

@interface Fraction: NSObject {
    struct myStructure {
        int numerator, denominatior;
    }objects[10];
}

-(void) print;
-(void) initialize;
@end

@implementation Fraction

-(void) initialize
{
    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
    {
        objects[i].numerator = (i+1);
        objects[i].denominatior = (i+2);
    }
}
-(void) print
{
    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\n", objects[i].numerator, objects[i].denominatior);
    }
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Fraction *obj = [[Fraction alloc] init];    
    [ obj initialize ];
    [ obj print ];

    [ obj release ];
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

[Switching to process 949]
Running…
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
6   7
7   8
8   9
9   10
10  11

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:0.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct element{

    NSString *name;
    float molarmass;

}elementZ;

elementZ[81] array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a init method within the implementation block of your Elements class:

```
- (id)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {

        for (int i=0; i<81; i++) {
            elements[i].name = "foo";
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

maybe some reading is required to get familar to Objective-C: [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

Object creation in Objective-C requires two steps:

- Allocation
- Initialization

E.g.:

```
Elements *e = [[Elements alloc] init];
```